# Failed to load web.xml in tomcat embedded 9

Tags: java, tomcat, web.xml

I hava problem with running a project with tomcat embedded 9.
My web.xml tacken from the tomcat web.xml example.

This is my gradel:

```
plugins {
  id 'java'
  id 'idea'
}

group 'com.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-core
  compile group: 'org.apache.tomcat.embed', name: 'tomcat-embed-core', version: '9.0.10'

  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-jasper
  compile group: 'org.apache.tomcat.embed', name: 'tomcat-embed-jasper', version: '8.0.52'
  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-logging-juli
  compile group: 'org.apache.tomcat.embed', name: 'tomcat-embed-logging-juli', version: '8.0.52'

  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.containers/jersey-container-servlet
  compile group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.containers', name: 'jersey-container-servlet', version: '2.27'
  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-server
  compile group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.core', name: 'jersey-server', version: '2.27'

  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.inject/jersey-hk2
  compile group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.inject', name: 'jersey-hk2', version: '2.27'

  testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

The main

```
import javax.servlet.ServletException;

import org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException;
import org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat;
import org.apache.catalina.Context;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception, LifecycleException {
    new Main().start();
  }

  public void start() throws ServletException, LifecycleException,
                             MalformedURLException {

    // Define a folder to hold web application contents.
    String webappDirLocation = "WebContent/";
    Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();

    // Define port number for the web application
    String webPort = System.getenv("PORT");
    if (webPort == null || webPort.isEmpty()) {
      webPort = "8080";
    }
    // Bind the port to Tomcat server
    tomcat.setPort(Integer.valueOf(webPort));

    // Define a web application context.
    Context context = tomcat.addWebapp("/tomcatembedded", new File(
        webappDirLocation).getAbsolutePath());

    // Define and bind web.xml file location.
    File configFile = new File(webappDirLocation + "WEB-INF/web.xml");
    context.setConfigFile(configFile.toURI().toURL());

    tomcat.start();
    tomcat.getServer().await();
  }

}
```

And the web.xml where the servlet and servlet-mapping are comented out, as i just try to load the web.xml correctly

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                      http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">

  <!--<servlet>-->
    <!--<servlet-name>REST Servlet</servlet-name>-->
    <!--<servlet-class>-->
      <!--org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer-->
    <!--</servlet-class>-->
    <!--<init-param>-->
      <!--<param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>-->
      <!--<param-value>com.example.resources</param-value>-->
    <!--</init-param>-->

    <!--<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>-->
  <!--</servlet>-->
  <!--<servlet-mapping>-->
    <!--<servlet-name>REST Servlet</servlet-name>-->
    <!--<url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>-->
  <!--</servlet-mapping>-->

</web-app>
```

When running main i get

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\java.exe" -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:50567,suspend=y,server=n -Dvisualvm.id=64887079117098 -javaagent:C:\Users\sb30123\.IntelliJIdea2018.1\system\groovyHotSwap\gragent.jar -javaagent:C:\Users\sb30123\.IntelliJIdea2018.1\system\captureAgent\debugger-agent.jar=file:/C:/Users/sb30123/AppData/Local/Temp/capture.props -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\repositories\embedded_tomcat_example\out\production\classes;C:\repositories\embedded_tomcat_example\out\production\resources;C:\Users\sb30123\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.tomcat.embed\tomcat-embed-core\9.0.10\fbf9dbc97babe8425332e6baf3925e8f726f3d7b\tomcat-embed-core-9.0.10.jar;C:\Users\sb30123\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.tomcat.embed\tomcat-embed-jasper\9.0.10\761ea6f3b09c163f3710f5e811693c0e7a66b5e8\tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.10.jar;C:\Users\sb30123\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.tomcat.embed\tomcat-embed-logging-juli\9.0.0.M6\2b083aa89d92ce10356158da1e643f8a8e890b49\tomcat-embed-logging-juli-9.0.0.M6.jar;C:\Users\sb30123\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.glassfish.jersey.containers\jersey-container-servlet\2.27\aa97ee9f6528706d1d7214f39a404297903a7598\jersey-container-servlet-2.27.jar;C:\Users\sb30123\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.glassfish.jersey.core\jersey-server\2.27\92c158af89e6749b20134c3182935046a49a1662\jersey-server-2.27.jar;C:\Users\sb30123\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.glassfish.jersey.inject\jersey-hk2\2.27\9ea08f93ee7045a36926954536ad385ac03b753f\jersey-hk2-2.27.jar;C:\Users\sb30123\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.tomcat\tomcat-annotations-api\9.0.10\18836b46b76d385615a738d5136fdbdaf9b0f32c\tomcat-annotations-api-9.0.10.jar;C:\Users\sb30123\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.tomcat.embed\tomcat-embed-el\9.0.10\7811474c12b6b3156a4b2c9d85d957c9542a7fd5\tomcat-embed-el-9.0.10.jar;C:\Users\sb30123\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.eclipse.jdt\ecj\3.13.102\d8061c14ff6388664299403791ae6bec487c12d7\ecj-3.13.102.jar;C:\Users\sb30123\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.glassfish.jersey.containers\jersey-container-servlet-core\2.27\81e24b17ff7cee96a1c830fe63aa1215176c009c\jersey-container-servlet-core-2.27.jar;C:\Users\sb30123\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.glassfish.jersey.core\jersey-common\2.27\f20d4304a476a92001930d75747adcc232dbe779\jersey-common-2.27.jar;C:\Users\sb30123\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\javax.ws.rs\javax.ws.rs-api\2.1\426a0862406536e690c7caa8bb6ed32191986fac\javax.ws.rs-api-2.1.jar;C:\Users\sb30123\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.glassfish.jersey.core\jersey-client\2.27\66dd6a62a981c0f186d96048fe11e9ddeca3ae28\jersey-client-2.27.jar;C:\Users\sb30123\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.glassfish.jersey.media\jersey-media-jaxb\2.27\106f2237ee03493185d9d915c9a1c011df716a2a\jersey-media-jaxb-2.27.jar;C:\Users\sb30123\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\javax.annotation\javax.annotation-api\1.2\479c1e06db31c432330183f5cae684163f186146\javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar;C:\Users\sb30123\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.glassfish.hk2.external\javax.inject\2.5.0-b42\98e0b7dcef77dc04809f0603868140a1c60bea71\javax.inject-2.5.0-b42.jar;C:\Users\sb30123\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\javax.validation\validation-api\1.1.0.Final\8613ae82954779d518631e05daa73a6a954817d5\validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\sb30123\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.glassfish.hk2\hk2-locator\2.5.0-b42\9d6edc0cb226401a8316e67d81bfc37cb626ef91\hk2-locator-2.5.0-b42.jar;C:\Users\sb30123\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.glassfish.hk2\osgi-resource-locator\1.0.1\4ed2b2d4738aed5786cfa64cba5a332779c4c708\osgi-resource-locator-1.0.1.jar;C:\Users\sb30123\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.glassfish.hk2.external\aopalliance-repackaged\2.5.0-b42\e74beab6ca12e9e745eb47ca61729d9452b96f0c\aopalliance-repackaged-2.5.0-b42.jar;C:\Users\sb30123\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.glassfish.hk2\hk2-api\2.5.0-b42\7fd4e3d0f2cb37c80ad0dedee3f5ee69503eaf52\hk2-api-2.5.0-b42.jar;C:\Users\sb30123\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.glassfish.hk2\hk2-utils\2.5.0-b42\102a344e1728825e865a8986d7605602aba3c3b6\hk2-utils-2.5.0-b42.jar;C:\Users\sb30123\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.javassist\javassist\3.22.0-CR2\44eaf0990dea92f4bca4b9931b2239c0e8756ee7\javassist-3.22.0-CR2.jar;C:\Users\sb30123\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\javax.inject\javax.inject\1\6975da39a7040257bd51d21a231b76c915872d38\javax.inject-1.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.4\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.example.Main
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:50567', transport: 'socket'
Jul 05, 2018 11:57:24 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Tomcat]
Jul 05, 2018 11:57:24 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/9.0.10
Jul 05, 2018 11:57:24 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'web-app'.
Jul 05, 2018 11:57:25 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig getDefaultWebXmlFragment
INFO: No global web.xml found
```

*******Edit According to @Rohi 's comment*******************

The project's structer is

```
embedded_tomcat_example
|-src
|  |-com
|  |  |-example
|  |  |  |-Main.java
|-WebContent
|  |-WEB-INF
|  |  |-web.xml
```

Someone can see the problem?

Comment: could you show the directory structure of your project?

Comment: Yes, i've added

Comment: Shouldn't you use `war` plugin?

Comment: war is for standalone tomcat, is'nt it? anyway, i've tried and there is no change

Comment: @rachel That message **"No global web.xml found"** is only an **INFO** message, not an error. What happens if you open http://localhost:8080/ anyway? See https://engineeernitesh.blogspot.com/2017/06/create-java-web-application-using.html  (I'm not understanding what is actually failing for you.)

Comment: This problem was probably similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66828015/11748454): since there is no `getConnector()` call, no connector is created and the server is unreachable.

Answer (score 0):

Changing to tomcat embedded 8.0.52 solved the problem