# Tomcat 9 complains about starting twice if I call connector.start()?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat9

I have a working Tomcat 8 + Spring 5 example, here: https://github.com/shorn/turnip/blob/8d73815ae361241ec3b4e8c71e2bb474898b9f06/src/main/java/turnip/App.java

You can see in the logs that Tomcat is listening on port 8080:

```
Mar 27, 2021 2:01:33 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: Initializing Servlet 'dispatcher'
Mar 27, 2021 2:01:33 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: Completed initialization in 6 ms
Mar 27, 2021 2:01:33 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
```

But when I upgraded to Tomcat 9, the startup process doesn't initialise the protocol listener:

```
Mar 27, 2021 2:10:14 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: Initializing Servlet 'dispatcher'
Mar 27, 2021 2:10:14 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: Completed initialization in 6 ms
```

That's the last lines in the log and it just sits there; when I tried to connect with a browser, Tomcat was not accepting connections on port 8080.

So then I added this code to "start" the protocol listener:

```
tomcat.getConnector().start();
```

This works, Tomcat is now listening to connections and Spring is servicing my endpoint.

But now Tomcat shows a message in the startup logs about calling `start()` twice:

```
Mar 27, 2021 2:16:16 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: Initializing Servlet 'dispatcher'
Mar 27, 2021 2:16:16 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: Completed initialization in 7 ms
Mar 27, 2021 2:16:16 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Mar 27, 2021 2:16:16 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Mar 27, 2021 2:16:16 PM org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase start
INFO: The start() method was called on component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]] after start() had already been called. The second call will be ignored.
```

Why does Tomcat 9 not listen to connections properly by default and what is the "correct" way to get an embedded Tomcat 9 running?

Answer (score 1):

You should call [`Tomcat#getConnector()`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/startup/Tomcat.html#getConnector--) **only** for its **side effect** of creating a `Connector`, before you call `Tomcat#start()`. Don't call the `start()` method on the returned connector, the startup sequence will do it for you.

IMHO this is a bug, since all those *"getters"* full of side effects should be called by the `Tomcat#start()` method.

**Edit**: digging a little dipper, the lack of default connector is an intentional change in [Tomcat 9.0.0.M14](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/changelog.html#Tomcat_9.0.0.M14_(markt)) as a reaction to [this regression bug report](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60368).

If I interpret the intentions of the devs correctly, you should rather create connectors yourself using:

```java
        Connector connector = new Connector("HTTP/1.1");
        connector.setPort(port);
        tomcat.setConnector(connector);
```

although for now `tomcat.getConnector()` has the same side effects.